# AWK - Need to display total value of field and field number

Tags: shell, awk, gawk

I have data below that needed to count or total the value start with specific field. Sample below the needed field to compute is from Field5.
For sample Field5 total is 42, field6 total is 107, etc..

Input file:

```
A,B,C,D,42,52,23,101,5,1,0,0,0
A,B,C,D,0,52,3,0,5,0,0,0,0
A,B,C,D,0,1,4,0,4,0,0,0,0
A,B,C,D,0,2,2,0,1,0,0,0,0
```

Expected output:

```
Field5=42, Field6=107, Field7=32, Field8=101, Field9=15, Field10=1
```

Trying to do with this code and I know its wrong. lol

```
echo "A,B,C,D,42,52,23,101,5,1,0,0,0
A,B,C,D,0,52,3,0,5,0,0,0,0
A,B,C,D,0,1,4,0,4,0,0,0,0
A,B,C,D,0,2,2,0,1,0,0,0,0" | awk -F"," '{for(i=0;i<=NF;i++){C++}} END {print i"=" C}'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
awk -F"," '{for (i=5;i<=NF;i++){a[i]=a[i]+$i}} END { for (i in a){ print "Field" i "=" a[i]}}' file
```

In your case it will print

```
Field5=42
Field6=107
Field7=32
Field8=101
Field9=15
Field10=1
Field11=0
Field12=0
Field13=0
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried with below awk and it worked like a charm; the commands are:

```
j=`awk -F ","  '{print NF}' filename| sort -nr| sed -n '1p'`
for ((i=5;i<=$j;i++)); do awk -v i="$i" -F "," 'BEGIN{sum=0}{sum=sum+$i}END {print "Field"i"=" sum}' filename; done| perl -pne "s/\n/, /g"
```

output:

```
Field5=42, Field6=107, Field7=32, Field8=101, Field9=15, Field10=1, Field11=0, Field12=0, Field13=0
```